# What is the lifetime of a transient dependency resolved via .UsingFactoryMethod but not explicitly resolved using the kernel?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle

I have the following class which exposes a public factory method instead of a public constructor:

```
public class SomeDependency
{
    private readonly string _someValue;
    private SomeDependency(string someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }

    public static SomeDependency CreateSomeDependency(string someValue)
    {
        return new SomeDependency(someValue);
    }
}
```

I configure it in the container to have a transient lifestyle and to be created via the static method:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<SomeDependency>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => SomeDependency.CreateSomeDependency("a value"))
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

All components that this dependency is injected into are configured to be transient as well.

Will the container dispose this dependency when objects that depend on it fall out of scope or will this dependency fail to be disposed and make everything stick around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be disposed if:

- It implements `IDisposable`, which it currently does not, **and**
- The composition root calls `Container.Release()` for the component that caused SomeDependency to be instantiated.

You cannot simply rely on the component going out of scope for disposal to be triggered.

If you are referring to garbage collection rather than disposal, then your current implementation may work ok with the object becoming available for GC when it goes out of scope. In most cases, transient components that do not implement IDisposable will not be tracked by the container but it can depend on what other facilities you are using in your container. Therefore, it is always best to ensure `Release` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Is the concern on the static method? If so, that should not cause an issue with marking an unused object for disposal. I am not sure I would use the pattern, but I don't see the entire motivation for the pattern in your post, so I can't judge.

If this were a Singleton (static variable served through a static method), you would not dispose, but that would be the intent of the pattern.

If you are seeing memory usage grow and worried about a memory leak, and thus asking the question, you can dig deeper, but it is more likely you are just seeing how .NET operates. Disposal happens as memory is needed, so it is normal to see .NET appearing to hold onto memory as if it was a memory leak. In almost every case I have investigated for clients who thought they had memory leaks, it was simply .NET not disposing of objects until memory was needed (default behavior).

If you are seeing a potential problem, there are ways to probe memory leaks in .NET. I would recommend using a tool rather than digging through dumpheap, but the pricing for certain tools may be prohibitive in some cases. You can use trials of various products if you simply need the peace of mind that you have not caused a memory leak.

Comment: A little detail on the pattern: The component is intended to be publicly usable but not publicly constructable due to incompatible types required to construct it. Instances of the object can be obtained by using the static factory method. A typed factory doesn't work because I am trying to keep the constructor private. Because I want to be able to isolate the object using DI having consuming code call the static method becomes problematic. Ultimately this comes down to the implementation details of the container.